# Hbase memory and garbage collection

Tags: java, hadoop, garbage-collection, hive, hbase

What is young generation and old generation in hbase memory concept? I have tried reading the concept in the book. But did not follow completely. Someone please help

Comment: Do you mean Java's young and old generation? http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/gc01/index.html

Comment: Hbase runs in jvm so yes Java's generational memory model you are asking about

Comment: i came with these 2 terms "young generation and old generation" in Hbase definitive guide. But could not follow . could you tell me what exactly that means